# MVC3 check for references to model record before deletion

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the best practice for checking if any references to a particular model record exist before deleting that record? Basically, I have a model that represents images, and all metadata associated with an image. Other models will have references to one or more images (depending on the model).

Let's say for example, I have an "Item" which has a "MainImage" and an "AltImage", both of which are just references to the Image model. If I delete an Item record, I have to check if the two images are referenced by any other Item, or any other table, and if not then delete the Image.
How would I go about this?

Comment: You mention that you're using ASP.NET MVC3, but what are you using for a DAL?  Are you executing queries directly in your controllers?

Comment: What I think @SoWeLie is getting at is that MVC has nothing whatsoever to do with creating or deleting records.  It is completely database agnostic.  You want to be asking your question of whatever database technology you are using, not MVC.

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework for my model generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a database, let it maintain referential integrity using foreign key constraints on the images. The database or EF will prevent you from deleting the image if it is still being referenced. You can catch this exception and continue processing the request without deleting the image.

I found a blog posting [Inferring Foreign Key Constraints in EF](http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/12/inferring-foreign-key-constraints-in.html) that may be of use in setting these up.

Answer (score 0):

**Couple ideas based on what you prefer:**

Create trigger in you DB

*That will delete alt img.
and everytime you want to delete the main record row the other record will be deleted too.*

Another (based on nhibernate)

*Make sure that alternative image in your entity framework might have possibility to cascade commands. And in that case if you delete one image the other one will be deleted too. [Here is one example from google how to do this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx)*

Most clumsy but easiest is:

*Delete both records when you deleting the image.*